# Is the Negative condition flag N also set with an Overflow?

Tags: assembly, cpu, processor

As I'm preparing for an assembly/processor architecture exam for school next week, I came across something rather confusing.

When performing a binary addition, we learned about 4 condition flags:

> N = result is negative
>
> Z = result is zero
>
> C = operation produced a carry
>
> V = operation produced overflow

But I'm a but confused about whether or not the N-flag has to be set when there is an overflow.

Let's consider this 4-bit addition in two's complement of 6+7 as an example:

```
0110
0111+
-----
1101  =  result
```

Now, when calculating in 4-bits with two's complement numbers, this obviously results in an overflow. It should result in 13 (01101 in 5 bits), but results in -3, because it can only be displayed in 4 bits.
So my question is, is the Negative flag N also set in this case? Because the result is a negative number.

Comment: Yes, it is set. The N flag is simply a copy of the most significant bit. Of course it can be set without an overflow too.

Comment: The sum of two negative numbers can overflow to a positive number, clearing `N`, so `V` and `N` are both relevant for addition as well as subtraction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't answer this question for certain without knowing exactly which processor you are using, but *usually* N is set equal to the high (sign) bit of the result, *independent of all other flags*.  So, in your example, both N and V will be set.

(N, Z, and C are almost always simple functions of the bits coming out of the ALU - C is the carry-out from the adder, N is equal to the high bit of the result, and Z is just NOT (OR (all the bits in the register)).  It's V whose definition is most likely to vary from processor to processor.)

Comment: Some ISAs differ on how C is set for subtraction (and `cmp`): on some, it's a "borrow" output, so `x-y` sets C when unsigned `x < y`, like on x86 where `sbb dst,src` (sub-with-borrow) does `dst -= (src+CF)` so extended-precision subtraction is easy.  But on some others, like ARM which uses these flag names, it's a NOT-borrow, and `sbc` (sub-with-carry) is designed appropriately so a subs / sbcs / sbcs still works just as easily. A !borrow is what you get directly from a hardware https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder%E2%80%93subtractor that subtracts by feeding an add-with-carry with `~a` and C=1

Answer (score 2):

With your 4-bit example case, continue considering with the following examples:

- 0001 + 1110 == 1111 (decimal: 1 + (-2) == -1)

Negative, but no overflow.

- 1100 + 1001 == 0101 (decimal: (-4) + (-7) == 5; -11 would be without overflow)

Not negative, but oveflowed.

This would show you negative flag does not relate directly to overflow fact.

But: the thing that is not usually explained: as soon as overflow flag means *sign is wrong*, one can detect *true result sign* as XOR of negative flag and overflow flag:

```
S = N xor V
```

where S is *true sign flag* (not present directly in NZVC scheme). This flag is virtually used in branch operations: when, for example, condition for BGT (PDP-11/ARM/etc. name) == JG (x86 name) is `((N xor V) or Z) == 0`, this really means `S or Z == 0`, or, in other words, `S == 0 and Z == 0`.

Also, this may be equally written as:

```
N = S xor V
```

and:

```
V = N xor S
```

(the latter is the closest to the formal defition of V flag).

Some instruction set architectures, e.g. AVR, have true sign flag (S) instead of negative flag in condition flag register (N).